# How to avoid type safety warning in number operation in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I write a class to perform number operation for different Number classes. However, I get type safety warning in every return statement.

Why does the return statement cause a type safety problem as I already know that, for example, both summand1 and summand2 are instance of Double? How can I avoid the warning?

```
 public class NumberOperation {
      public static <R extends Number & Comparable<R>> R addition(R summand1, R summand2) {
           if (!summand1.getClass().equals(summand2.getClass()))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Two different classes are used in the parameters: " + summand1.getClass().getName() + ", " + summand2.getClass().getName());
           if(summand1 instanceof Double && summand2 instanceof Double)
                return (R) new Double(summand1.doubleValue() + summand2.doubleValue());
           else if(summand1 instanceof Float && summand2 instanceof Float)
                return (R) new Float(summand1.floatValue() + summand2.floatValue());
           else if(summand1 instanceof Long && summand2 instanceof Long)
                return (R) new Long(summand1.longValue() + summand2.longValue());
           else if(summand1 instanceof Integer && summand2 instanceof Integer)
                return (R) new Integer(summand1.intValue() + summand2.intValue());
           else if(summand1 instanceof Short && summand2 instanceof Short)
                return (R) new Short((short) (summand1.shortValue() + summand2.shortValue()));
           else if(summand1 instanceof Byte && summand2 instanceof Byte)
                return (R) new Byte((byte) (summand1.byteValue() + summand2.byteValue()));
           else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(summand1.getClass().getName() + " is not supported.");
      }
 }
```

Comment: why would you write something like this?

Comment: Is there anything here which can not be handled with BigDecimal?

Comment: I write it because I have another class about range, and I will use both Integer, Long and Double there. I need to do number operation for methods in that class, but I don't want to write 3 classes like RangeInt, RangeDouble, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this problem more difficult than it is. Maybe BigDecimal etc can do all of this for you. But if you want to stick to your code, it works if you remove all the generics:

```
public static Number addition(Number summand1, Number summand2) {
     if (!summand1.getClass().equals(summand2.getClass()))
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Two different classes are used in the parameters: " + summand1.getClass().getName() + ", " + summand2.getClass().getName());
     if(summand1 instanceof Double && summand2 instanceof Double)
          return new Double(summand1.doubleValue() + summand2.doubleValue());
     else if(summand1 instanceof Float && summand2 instanceof Float)
          return new Float(summand1.floatValue() + summand2.floatValue());
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I make things too complicated at the beginning...  And BigDecimal seems to be a good alternative in my case.